# Finding mean by grouping by hour from minutes

Tags: r

Here's a snippet of the data table I am working with

```
timestamp            temperature    humidity
2017-01-01 05:00:00  1.6994955556   92.40667
2017-01-01 05:15:00 -1.0252000000   NA
2017-01-01 05:20:00 -1.0464666667   NA
2017-01-01 05:25:00 -1.0394000000   NA
2017-01-01 05:30:00 -1.1201333333   NA
2017-01-01 05:35:00 -1.1132000000   NA
2017-01-01 05:40:00 -1.0979333333   NA
2017-01-01 05:45:00 -1.1047333333   NA
2017-01-01 05:50:00 -1.0839333333   NA
2017-01-01 05:55:00 -1.0742666667   NA
2017-01-01 06:00:00  1.0925769231   92.27000
2017-01-01 06:05:00 -1.0227333333   NA
2017-01-01 06:10:00 -1.0104000000   NA
2017-01-01 06:15:00 -0.9828000000   NA
2017-01-01 06:20:00 -0.9466666667   NA
2017-01-01 06:25:00 -0.9382666667   NA
2017-01-01 06:30:00 -0.9409333333   NA
2017-01-01 06:35:00 -0.9480666667   NA
2017-01-01 06:40:00 -0.9214666667   NA
2017-01-01 06:45:00 -1.0034000000   NA
2017-01-01 06:50:00 -1.1557333333   NA
2017-01-01 06:55:00 -1.1392000000   NA
2017-01-01 07:00:00  0.9641743590   92.57500
2017-01-01 07:05:00 -1.2462666667   NA
2017-01-01 07:10:00 -1.2434000000   NA
2017-01-01 07:15:00 -1.3654000000   NA
2017-01-01 07:20:00 -1.4027333333   NA
2017-01-01 07:25:00 -1.4692666667   NA
2017-01-01 07:30:00 -1.2844666667   NA
2017-01-01 07:35:00 -1.2317333333   NA
2017-01-01 07:40:00 -1.3346666667   NA
2017-01-01 07:45:00 -1.2498000000   NA
2017-01-01 07:50:00 -1.2679333333   NA
2017-01-01 07:55:00 -1.3306666667   NA
2017-01-01 08:00:00  0.8240705128   92.84000
```

The timestamps are logged every 5 minutes. I intend to group the timestamps by the hour and find the mean temperature for that hour so that I can clear up the NA cells.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can `cut` the data on each hour and take `mean` of `temperature` :

```
aggregate(temperature~group, transform(df, group = cut(timestamp, 'hour')), mean)
```

---

Using `lubridate` you can use `floor_date`/`ceiling_date` to get hourly intervals.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(hour = floor_date(timestamp, 'hour')) %>%
  summarise(temperatire = mean(temperature))
```